# iOS: jumpy animation when changing orientation, setFrame

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect, uiinterfaceorientation, uiviewanimation

I'm using the code below to set up a view when the orientation changes on an iOS device. This works to give me the shape I want (wider and same height), but the animation is jumpy when changing orientations. If I hide the `setFrame` code the animation is perfectly smooth, but of course the shape does not get wider. I tried adding a transform, but so far it distorts the shape of the view in undesirable way (as the view contains a complex drawn shape with rounded corners etc).

```
[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width-20, 170)];     
[myView setNeedsDisplay];     
CGPoint viewCenter = CGPointMake((myView.frame.size.width/2)+someNum (self.view.bounds.size.height-(someOtherNum/2)-anotherNum));     
myView.center = viewCenter;

//quick unsuccessful test to see if transforms would work:
//myView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.5, 1);
```

Any help with this? Is there a way to get my result without the jumpy animation?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried UIViewAnimation?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    [myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width-20, 170)];     
    [myView setNeedsDisplay];     
    CGPoint viewCenter = CGPointMake((myView.frame.size.width/2) + someNum
    (self.view.bounds.size.height-(someOtherNum/2)-anotherNum));
    myView.center = viewCenter;
}];
```